# Gzipped archives - Create using tar -czf and extract using only -xf?

Tags: tar, gzip

Say I have a `file.txt` containing one line:

```
strawberry
```

Using

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz file.txt
```

I can create a "gzipped archive" with the name `archive.tar.gz`, which is to my knowledge the equivalent of doing

```
tar -cf archive.tar file.txt
gzip archive.tar
```

Now, to extract `archive.tar.gz`, I would use

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz
```

to get my `file.txt`. This should be the equivalent of doing

```
gzip -d archive.tar.gz
tar -xf archive.tar
```

However, if I just use the command

```
tar -xf archive.tar.gz
```

without decompressing the file first through `gzip` or the `--gzip` option in tar, I *still* get my `file.txt` and can read the content.

I changed the file ending from `archive.tar.gz` to just `archive.tar` and got the same results.

How does tar know that it has to decompress the file first given that the file ending can be changed by the user? Do I miss some essential knowledge about file storing that allows tar to notice the compression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr - GNU `tar` is smart

In the good old, bad old days you had to do exactly as you say and use `-xzf`. Nowadays, `tar` opens the archive, has a quick peek and if the contents look compressed then it invokes uncompress automatically for you. And that's it. You can take a look at `man tar` to see what compression algorithms it supports.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess I should stop using https://ss64.com/ as reference for unix commands and just use `man`. I took a look at `tar` and found what I was looking for: _[...] this implementation recognizes gzip compression automatically when reading archives._